# passing values to the string objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a confirmation form containing different textFields like Name, Age, Phone no., Email etc. Now i want to use them into mail and send them to the user. I have done that. My application mail is working perfectly fine.

Now i want in the mail which i sent to user through application it should contain these information in structured way. i used string like :

```
 NSString * bodyMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello  Customer Details:-  Cutomer name: %@,%@,@%",labelName.text, labelEmail.text,labelPhone.text];
```

But it shows unstructed data.

I want the mail should be :

```
Name : manjinder
Email: mann@tmail.com
Phone: 098873424345t
```

How can i display like this.

Comment: You could use HTML. Most mail clients can show HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... = [NSString stringWithFomat:@"Name\t: %@\r\nEmail\t: %@\r\nPhone\t: %@",
                                labelName.text,
                                labelEmail.text,
                                labelPhone.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding line breaks:

```
NSString * bodyMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello  Customer Details:-  Cutomer name: %@\n%@\n%@\n",labelName.text, labelEmail.text,labelPhone.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTML line breaks in the string to accomplish that:

```
<br />
```

Just remember to set the HTML flag of the following call that you make on your MFMailComposeViewController:

```
[myMailController setMessageBody: myEmailBodyString isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: ASCII does support new lines too =).

Comment: i am not using MFMailController. i m using third party mail library

Comment: Why aren't you using MFMailController?

Comment: @Tim: Yep, just adding additional ways this can be accomplished.

Comment: @Luke, okay! For example, if he would want to use text-formatting, HTML indeed is the only option available ;)!

Comment: @dasdom coz i want to send email at back ground.

Comment: I have another question "Problem in passing dynamic location coordinates into google places string" i have asked it on this website. despite of many times asking same question no body solved it. please have a look if u can solve. it. I really appriciate that